# ¿Cómo asigno un array como valor del atributo de un objeto desde que se instancia? en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando la [API de Pokemon](https://pokeapi.co/) e instanciando 2 pokemon elegidos, este es el constructor de la clase y el metodo que instancía los objetos:

```
class Pokemon {
    constructor(id, name, type, attacks, level, imgFront, imgBack) {
        this.id       = id
        this.name     = name
        this.type     = type
        this.attacks  = attacks
        this.level    = level
        this.imgFront = imgFront
        this.imgBack  = imgBack
    }
}

//De una lista que se muestra en pantalla el usuario selecciona por el ID y se ejcuta la siguiente funcón
function choosePokemon(n) {
    var i = n-1
    var p = listaPokemonDisponibles[i]
      //listaPokemonDisponibles es un array que contiene los pokemon obtenidos con otro metodo

    pokemonSelected = new Pokemon(p.id, p.name, p.types[0].type.name, [0:{p.moves[0].move.name}, 1:{p.moves[1].move.name}, 2:{p.moves[2].move.name}], p.base_experience, p.sprites.front_default, p.sprites.back_default)

    if (turno == 1) {
        pokemon1 = pokemonSelected
    }else{
        pokemon2 = pokemonSelected
    }
}
```

En attacks quiero almacenar un array con 3 valores de los primeros 3 arrays del atributo "moves" del objeto que mando a llamar

> (Objeto[5].moves[0].move.name, Objeto[5].moves[1].move.name,
>   Objeto[5].moves[2].move.name)

Ya que el atributo "moves" del objeto contiene muchos arrays 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Digamos que quiero lograr que el resultado sea este:

```
Pokemon {
    id: 6
    name: "charizard"
    type: "flying"
    level: 240
    attacks: {
        0: "mega-punch",
        1: "fire-punch",
        2: "thunder-punch"
    }
    imgFront: "https:...pokemon/6.png"
    imgBack: "https:...pokemon/back/6.png"
}
```

Si guardo solo un valor si me funciona(tal como guardo solo un "type"), pero no logro conseguir guardar un array. Gracias desde ya.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu solución sería mediante un **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map)**

```
const moves = moves.slice(0, 3).map(x => ({ name: x.move.name }))
```

Con **[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice)** indicas que sólo necesitas 3 elementos del arreglo e iteras este elemento extrayendo la información que necesitas

Te dejo un ejemplo práctico

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'uno', value: 1 },
  { name: 'dos', value: 2 },
  { name: 'tres', value: 3 },
  { name: 'cuatro', value: 4 }
]

const aux = data.slice(0, 3);
console.log(aux)
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta crack!

Comment: Excelente!, gracias a ambos. Pude asignar los tres valores que necesitaba a la constante dentro de la función y después usar esta constante al instanciar el nuevo Objeto.

Comment: @JuanGF recuerda que el objeto es cuando se hacen copias se conoce como `shadow copy`(copia de sombra) donde solo copia los primeros elemento del objeto y los demas quedan como referencia, al ser referencia si se cambia en en un lado se cambia en otro

Answer (score 0):

Ya que no muestras un ejemplo de la estructura completa del **JSON** realice una estructura json simple para que puedas darte un ejemplo.

1. utilizamos la estructura completa que contiene toda la info del pokemon y en tu constructor podrías enviar simplemente un array que contiene el id de cada ataque a utilizar.
2. usamos el [operador Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread) para obtener los ataques con ayuda del las funciones map y filter.

```js
let pokemon_json = {
  5: [{
    abilities: [{
      0: 'dia soleado'
    }, {
      1: 'otro'
    }],
    moves: [{
      id :1, name: 'fire-punch'
    }, {
      id :2, name:'drain-punch'
    }, {
      id :3, name: 'slash'
    }, {
      id :4, name: 'thunder-punch'
    }, {
     id :5, name: 'mega-punch'
    }, {
     id :6, name: 'bulk-up'
    }]
  }]
};

const crearPokemon = (id, name, type, level, attacks, pokemon_json) => {
  let array = {
    id: id,
    name: name,
    level: level,
    attacks: {...attacks.map((el) => {
 return pokemon_json[5][0].moves.filter((e) => {
        if (e.id === el) {
          return e.name;
        }
        })[0].name
      })}
  };// end array
console.log(array);
      }


crearPokemon(1,'abc','fire',100,[1,3,4],pokemon_json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias @stan, también llega al resultado pero de esta manera estaría generando un **JSON** mediante una función en lugar de **instanciar un Objeto de la clase Pokemón**.

Comment: que hace `if (e.id === el) {`??

Comment: Si e.id que es el id del pokemon es igual al numero de id en el array o elemento **el** hace el return para obtener el nombre del ataque